# How to replace Table Layout with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm developing an Android application, what that i want to do is replace Table layout with ListView.

Actually i use a Table and a Scrollable Layout to display some information like a  list, my data are contained in a XML file that i parse with XMLpullparser, data are saved in an array list.

My array is composed by "Category name" (for example FOODS) and "Item name" (for example pizza, maccheroni, fish, chips), i want to display this data in this mode:

Category name

List item

Category name

List item

Category name

List item

Important: each datas MUST have particulars style, (Category name must have a certain background color, font size, font color ecc and List item must have a certain style).

Using Table layout i have this result, 'cause every row of my table can have differents style, but how i can do this with a listview ?

This is a little example of my xml

```
<data>
  <category_name name="FOODS">
   <item item_name="pizza"></item>      
   <item item_name="pasta"></item>            
   </category>        
</data>
```

Using pullparser i save my data in an array

Comment: with listView you can make your own adapter, and apply different style to each row.

Comment: You can make custom Adaper class and apply background color to particular row of ListView using its position.

Comment: Ok, but how i can apply some style only to "Category name" and other style to "item name" i haven't a id row..

Use the position might not be the correct choice, I don't know a priori where you can find the category or the objects of the category

Comment: @Mattia Are you aware of Custom ListView?

Comment: You should make a model class, that you can retrieve in adapter's getView method, so you can check if the row object belongs to determinate category

Comment: @X'Factor no, I was not aware, I found a few examples on google, thanks

And thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

If you make your own model class, with a property category, its constructor and their getters and settes like:

```
public class Food {

private String category;

public Food(String category) {
    super();
    this.category = category;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
```

}

After that, in your main code you put all the elements in ArrayList:

```
final ArrayList<Food> elements = new ArrayList<Food>();

    elements.add(new Food("pizza"));
    elements.add(new Food("pasta"));

    final FoodAdapter adapter = new FoodAdapter(this, 0, elements);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then make custom adapter:

```
public class FoodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

private ArrayList<Food> elements;

public FoodAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Food> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.elements = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(elements.get(position).getCategory().equals("pizza")){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000);
    }else if(elements.get(position).getCategory().equals("pasta")){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF);
    }

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

If you follow the code, the pizza elements will have red background, and pasta will be blue.